# How to find duplicated data in first column based on second column and show result as Status in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have one thing to solve.I want to add new column as "Complete or Not" deponding on Action Column.If one date have sign_in and sign_out,data in new column is "Complete" for that date.

Pls help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjeaz.gif)

Comment: Pls check here [Link] https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Identify-duplicates-and-show-up-records/td-p/210061

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.